# Dynamically added labels only show one

Tags: c#, forms, dynamic, controls, panel

Ok so I decided to add controls to a panel on form_load based on labels in an array. Below is my code, but no matter how many files I upload through the button listener and reload this form, it only displays one label and nothing more. Why is it only displaying one? I have added a breakpoint and verified that the count does go up to 2, 3, etc.

**Code:**

```
public partial class Attachments : Form
    {
        ArrayList attachmentFiles;
        ArrayList attachmentNames;
        public Attachments(ArrayList attachments, ArrayList attachmentFileNames)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            attachmentFiles = attachments;
            attachmentNames = attachmentFileNames;
        }

        private void Attachments_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScrollBar vScrollBar1 = new VScrollBar();
            vScrollBar1.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
            vScrollBar1.Scroll += (sender2, e2) => { pnl_Attachments.VerticalScroll.Value = vScrollBar1.Value; };
            pnl_Attachments.Controls.Add(vScrollBar1);
            Label fileName;
            for (int i = 0; i < attachmentNames.Count; i++)
            {
                fileName = new Label();
                fileName.Text = attachmentNames[i].ToString();
                pnl_Attachments.Controls.Add(fileName);
            }
        }

        private void btn_AddAttachment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                attachmentFiles.Add(fileName);
                attachmentNames.Add(Path.GetFileName(fileName));
                this.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the labels are all stacking on top of each other. You will need to specify a top for each one or use an auto-flow panel.

Adding the following line after creating the new label will ensure all labels are visible (you may have to adjust the multiplier depending on your font):

```
fileName.Top = (i + 1) * 22;
```

Answer (score 0):

As [competent_tech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1002323/competent-tech) stated the labels are stacking on top of each other, but another approach is to modify the location value of the label.The benefit to this is you can control the absolute location of the label.

```
fileName.Location = new Point(x, y);
y += marginAmount;
```

x is the vertical position on the form and y is the horizontal location on the form. Then all that has to be modified is the amount of space you want in between each label in the marginAmount variable.

So in this for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < attachmentNames.Count; i++)
{
    fileName = new Label();
    fileName.Text = attachmentNames[i].ToString();
    pnl_Attachments.Controls.Add(fileName);
}
```

You could modify it to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < attachmentNames.Count; i++)
{
    fileName = new Label();
    fileName.Text = attachmentNames[i].ToString();
    fileName.Location = new Point(x, y);
    y += marginAmount;
    pnl_Attachments.Controls.Add(fileName);
}
```

Then all you have to do is define x, y, and the marginAmount.